# Android: Works on 5.1, but doesn't on 7.0

Tags: android, server, messaging

I am currently trying to write a GPS based chat application. The application works just fine an emulator running Android 5.1, but I am given an error when using an emulator running android 7.0, and am unable to figure out why. The error I am being given is the following:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                          at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
>                                                                                          at
>   java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
>                                                                                          at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:157)
>                                                                                          at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1946)
>                                                                                          at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1833)
>                                                                                          at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1229)
>                                                                                          at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.liftedstarfish.lifte.gpschat0_2.Client.sendMessage(Client.java:90)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.liftedstarfish.lifte.gpschat0_2.ClientActivity$1.onClick(ClientActivity.java:87)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Again, the error exists only when using android 7.0. 5.1 works. The code for the class in which the error appears is shown bellow. The locations of the errors have large arrows around them.

Client Class:

```
public class Client implements Parcelable{

    // for I/O
    private ObjectInputStream serverInput;      // to read from the socket
    private ObjectOutputStream serverOutput;        // to write on the socket
    private Socket socket;

    // if I use a GUI or not
    private ConnectActivity connectActivity;
    private ClientActivity clientActivity;

    // the server, the port and the username
    private String server, username;
    private int port;

    // for GPS location
    private static Double coordinates[] = new Double[]{0.0, 0.0};

    public Client(String server, int port, String username)
    {
        this(server, port, username, null, null);
    }

    public Client(String server, int port, String username, ClientActivity clientActivity)
    {
        this(server, port, username, clientActivity, null);
    }
    /*
     * Constructor call when used from a GUI
     * in console mode the ClienGUI parameter is null
     */
    public Client(String server, int port, String username, ClientActivity clientActivity, ConnectActivity connectActivity) {
        this.server = server;
        this.port = port;
        this.username = username;
        // save if we are in GUI mode or not
        this.connectActivity = connectActivity;
        this.clientActivity = clientActivity;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(double X, double Y)
    {
        setCoordinates(new Double[]{X, Y});
    }

    public void setCoordinates(Double[] coordinates)
    {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.LOCATION_UPDATE, "", coordinates));
    }

    /*
     * To start the dialog
     */
    public void start() {new ConnectToServer().start();}
    /*
     * To send a message to the console or the GUI
     */
    private void display(String message)
    {
        if(connectActivity == null) System.out.println(message);      // println in console mode
        else connectActivity.append(message);       // append to the ClientGUI JTextArea (or whatever)
    }

    public void setClientActivity(ClientActivity clientActivity)
    {
        this.clientActivity = clientActivity;
    }

    /*
     * To send a message to the server
     */
    public void sendMessage(ChatMessage message)
    {
        try
        {
>>>>>>>>>>>>serverOutput.writeObject(message);<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            display("Exception writing to server: " + e);
        }
    }

    /*
     * When something goes wrong
     * Close the Input/Output streams and disconnect not much to do in the catch clause
     */
    public void disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            if(serverInput != null) serverInput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {} // not much else I can do
        try
        {
            if(serverOutput != null) serverOutput.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {} // not much else I can do
        try
        {
            if(socket != null) socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {} // not much else I can do

        // inform the GUI
        if(clientActivity != null)
            clientActivity.connectionFailed();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int portNumber = 1500;
        String serverAddress = "localHost";
        String userName = "Anonymous";

        switch(args.length)
        {

            case 3:
                serverAddress = args[2];

            case 2:
                try {portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);}
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid port number.");
                    System.out.println("Usage is: > java Client [username] [portNumber] [serverAddress]");
                    return;
                }

            case 1:
                userName = args[0];

            case 0:
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Usage is: > java Client [username] [portNumber] {serverAddress]");
                return;
        }
        // create the Client object
        Client client = new Client(serverAddress, portNumber, userName);

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("> ");

            String message = scan.nextLine();

            if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("LOGOUT"))
            {
                client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.LOGOUT, "", coordinates));
                break;
            }
            //else if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("WHOISIN"))
            //{
            //    client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.WHOISIN, ""));
            //}
            else if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("LOCATION_UPDATE"))
            {
                client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.LOCATION_UPDATE, message, coordinates));
            }
            else
                client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.MESSAGE, message, coordinates));
        }

        client.disconnect();
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        dest.writeString(server);
        dest.writeString(username);
        dest.writeInt(port);
    }

    public int describeContents() {return 0;}

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Client> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<Client>()
    {
        public Client createFromParcel(Parcel in) {return new Client(in);}
        public Client[] newArray(int size) {return new Client[size];}
    };

    private Client(Parcel in)
    {
        server = in.readString();
        username = in.readString();
        port = in.readInt();
        new ConnectToServer().start();
    }

    class ConnectToServer extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try {socket = new Socket(server, port);}
            catch(Exception ec) {display("Error connecting to server:" + ec);}

            try
            {
                serverInput  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                serverOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            }
            catch (IOException eIO) {display("Exception creating new Input/output Streams: " + eIO);}

            // creates the Thread to listen from the server
            new ListenToServer().start();

            try {serverOutput.writeObject(username);}
            catch (IOException eIO)
            {
                display("Exception logging in: " + eIO);
                disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

    class ListenToServer extends Thread {

        public void run()
        {
            Looper.prepare();
            while(true)
            {
                try
                {
                    final String message = (String) serverInput.readObject();

                    if(clientActivity == null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(message);
                        System.out.print("> ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        clientActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                clientActivity.append(message);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    clientActivity.connectionFailed();
                    display("Server has closed the connection: " + e);
                    break;
                }

                catch(ClassNotFoundException e2){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ClientActivity class:

```
public class ClientActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // for I/O
    private Client client;

    //Display Objects
    private TextView lblMessages;
    private TextView lblLocation;

    //Mathematical value of PI (3.14159...)
    private static final double PI = Math.PI;

    //Used for finding client location
    private double LAT, LON;

    //coordinates is used for storing the coordinates in miles
    private Double coordinates[] = new Double[]{0.0, 0.0};

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            client = bundle.getParcelable("CLIENT");
        }

        client.setClientActivity(ClientActivity.this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //Checks for user permissions
        if(!runtimePermissions())
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPS_Service.class);
            startService(intent);
        }

        //Obtains Updated location when it is requested.


        final TextView lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_location);
        this.lblLocation = lblLocation;
        lblLocation.setText("LOCATION: X: " + coordinates[0] + " Y: " + coordinates[1]);

        final TextView lblMessages = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_messages);
        this.lblMessages = lblMessages;

        final EditText txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_message);

        final Button btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
                txtMessage.setText("");

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.MESSAGE, message, coordinates));<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            }
        });

        final Button btnLogOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_log_out);
        btnLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.LOGOUT, "", coordinates));
                client.disconnect();
            }
        });

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if(broadcastReceiver == null)
        {
            broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
            {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
                {
                    coordinates = (Double[]) intent.getExtras().get("coordinates");

                    lblLocation.setText("LOCATION: X: " + coordinates[0] + " Y: " + coordinates[1]);
                }
            };
        }

        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("LocationUpdate"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        if(broadcastReceiver != null)
        {
            unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }
    }

    private boolean runtimePermissions()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[]
                    {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    }, 100);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(requestCode == 100 &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GPS_Service.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            runtimePermissions();
        }
    }


    public void connectionFailed()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConnectActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

//    public void display(String msg) {lblMessages.append("Error" + msg);}

    //Adds a message to the message display section
    public void append(String str) {lblMessages.append(str + "\n");}
}
```

Comment: The post title is annoying. Please [edit] the title.

Answer (score 0):

Put the executed code in an AsyncTask.

EX:

```
public class ChatService extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

    Context c;

    public ChatService (Context x){

        c=x;

    }
    private static Client client;
    public ChatService setClient(Client client)
    {
       this.client = client;
       return this; //will do ;)
    }
    private static ChatMessage mChat;
    public ChatService setChatMessage(ChatMessage mChat)
    {
       this.mChat = mChat;
       return this; //already did, what do you want from me?!
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String message = "";
        client.sendMessage(mChat);
        return message;
    }

    PackageInfo pi;

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
      //Add text to Views
    }

}
```

And to execute this code:

```
//out in the middle of no where
//appears a random wild code
//we must protect this code
protected void wildCode()
{
     ChatService cs = new ChatService(this)
                .setClient(client)
                .setChatMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.MESSAGE, message, coordinates));
      cs.execute();
}
```

If you want to add AsyncTask without making a mess (class, lol), use this:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void,String> task = new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>() {
    private static Client client;
    public void setClient(Client client)
    {
       this.client = client;

    }
    private static ChatMessage mChat;
    public void setChatMessage(ChatMessage mChat)
    {
       this.mChat = mChat;

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String message = "";
        client.sendMessage(mChat);
        return message;
    }

    PackageInfo pi;

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
      //Add text to Views
    }

};

task.setClient(client);
task.setChatMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.MESSAGE, message, location));
task.execute();
```

Comment: I'll modify this once I look at your code. If you want, you can upload it to GitHub and I can help you out from there.

Comment: That would be Apreciated. I'm not quite sure how to use GitHub though. I am doing this for a project that is due on the 2nd. I had a working app, but then the android 7.0 bug came up, so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Exclude Android 7.0 for the time being. I'd suggest posting a pic of the bug here so we can see.

FYI: GitHub isn't that though. All you have to do is create an account, create the repository for this project (check add README or you're gonna have a baaad time), then just drag the code from its directory to the page.

Comment: NVM don't exclude it. 7.0 is very network secure. This should fix your issue. You don't have to create a class by the way. Just make an AsyncTask in your code ( AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>()) and add the unimplemented code. Then execute it.

Comment: I have no clue how to use AsyncTask. I've tried looking at the documentation, but it is no help.

Comment: What's your email? I'll send you a sample.

Comment: alexander.c.hargraves@outlook.com

Comment: I just sent you the code - the class implementation. This is just a security measure android takes.

Comment: I recieved your email. I would like to know, however where in the program would I place the code?

Comment: Place it in the activity

Answer (score 0):

As the Exception says, you're trying to do some network and data consumption tasks (get data from GPS). By default, android it's designed to avoid that kind of work on the MainThread (where the User Interface runs).

To fix that, you can use AsyncTask, Handlers, Threads or even Services to request and get the information you need from the GPS, Network or even Files on your SD Card.

Comment: I have had this error before, and I have fixed it. However, I fixed it on android 5.1, but it resurfaced on android 7.0

Comment: How did yous solved the error on Android 5.1?

Maybe the way you did it wasn't right, and some of the new changes on Android 7 expect this to be avoided at all.